# Triggering process from Platform Event started by REST Guest User?

Tags: process-builder, platform-event

I'm creating a process that is triggered by a Platform Event, resulting from an incoming API call via REST Guest User context.

I want the process to fire a custom notification, but it's not working. For testing, I added an action to post to chatter, but I get an error that REST Guest User can't post to chatter.

That's why I'm using a Platform Event -- to abstract this from the Guest User context. I thought Process Builder ran in System Context anyway.

What am I missing?

Comment: There are some permission limitations for the Automated Process user (the contextual user for trigger-based platform event consumers) which could prevent you doing notifications from the platform event processing.

Comment: System Mode != running user context - but I would expect that the process runs in a separate transaction in the context of the automated process user, and I would also expect that the automated process user can't post to Chatter either. Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Any ideas how I can abstract this so that an incoming event can fire the Custom Notification? If I call invocable APEX would that change/mask the user context? Or probably easier just to write a trigger on the Platform event, (though I really wanted to leave that choice to the customer.)

Comment: Just read that you can't access Custom Notifications via APEX...